# Trying to position text specifically with CSS, and allow it to move with the page

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
p.titletext
{
font-family:"arial";
font-size:50px;
position:relative;
left:425px;
top:10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="titletext">Hello World.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm asking whether there's anything that can handle text positioning that will actually keep the text in its position while the page is being expanded/contracted.  In other words, I want the text positioning to following according to the page size.  For example, if I make a new paragraph and align it to the center, no matter how large or small the window is, the text will always stay in the center.  Is there a way to accomplish this while setting the text position to your liking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
body{text-align:center;}
p.titletext
{
font-family:"arial";
font-size:50px;
}
```

UPDATE:-for both horizontal and vertical

```
<style type="text/css">

p.titletext
{ position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; height:2em; margin-top:-1em; width:40%; margin-left:-20%;text-align:center; 
font-family:"arial";
font-size:50px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: How can I set my text to align in the center and position it, say, 100 pixels from the top?

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by `text-align:center` and `top:50%` in `p.titletext` and remove `position:relative` so it will always on center

Comment: this method will not work for element that have display:inline

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble  sir, he aint say that he is using display:inline